# Time changes suddenly even though NTP is configured

Tags: sles, ntp

If have SLES 11 SP2 and this is the problem:

I have configured the NTP service and when I restart it then it is synchronizing correctly the time.

Then, suddenly after around 7-8 minutes the time changes. Here is a log of the `date` command displayed every 10 seconds:

```
Tue May 24 20:11:35 CEST 2016
Tue May 24 20:10:38 CEST 2016   <-- Restart of the NTP service
Tue May 24 20:10:48 CEST 2016
....
Tue May 24 20:17:59 CEST 2016
Tue May 24 20:19:16 CEST 2016   <-- Here it changed
```

What can be the problem?

**Update**:

1. Yes, it is a VM on a XenServer 6.5
2. No, in `/var/log/messages/` there is **NO** entry when the time changed.
3. Output of `ntpq -p`:

> ```
>  remote           refid           st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
>  ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>  LOCAL(0)        .LOCL.           10 l   24   64  377    0.000    0.000   0.001
>  *rs000486.fastro 192.53.103.108   2 u  119  256  377   21.547  -66949.   1.243
> ```

**Update:**

I have in total 10 Linux SLES 11 SP2 VM located on 2 host systems: 1 system is XenServer 6.5 and the other is XenServer 6.0. This issue is only on the host with XenServer 6.5 - all VMs running on host with XenServer 6.0 **don't** have this issue.

I copied the `/etc/ntp.conf`  file from the correct running VM but no change.

Comment: Is this a virtual machine ?  Anything pertinent written to `/var/log/messages ` during the period ? What does `ntpq -p` show ?

Comment: @steve I updated my question with the requested information.

Comment: Try removing the local server from your ntp.conf ?

Comment: @steve No change. after 8 minutes the time changed again. **No** entry in `/var/log/messages` nor in `/var/log/ntp`!

Comment: Is it a VMware vm?

Comment: Ah ok. Sorry missed that! I just wondered as I had a similar issue with VMware guests a year or so ago and the answer was I had to configure guests to ignore the hardware clock of the host.

Comment: Is the time on the xenserver 6.5's dom0 correct? Are you using paravirtualization or hvm?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick You are the best! The time on the XenServer 6.5 is exactly what is *replicated* to the VMs on the host.The `ntp` service is running on the host and therefore I don't understand why the time is wrong. At least now we know why the time is wrong. I don't have to run the `ntp` client on the VMs - they are synchronized by XenServer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sysadmiral` was already on the correct path and `Mark Plotnick`  finalized the thought. The XenServer host has a wrong time and this time is then *replicated* to the VMs.

That far the reason for my question has been found and now I have to sort out how to correct the time issue on the XenServer but this may be another question.

I can now - according to `sysadmiral` - configure the clients to ignore the host or set the correct time on the host. The last option has the advantage that I do not have to configure the `ntp` service at all...

Comment: Although for instance, VmWare advises not to sync from the host time, I do it. I do not know the full explanation, however saving a little memory/CPU seems to be beneficial to the VMs, it is one less service to administer/update and on top of that, ntp daemons have had historically lots of security problems. It also fits like a glove to the philosophy of Unix of only installing and running the strictly necessary services. Nevertheless, if you have services that are highly dependent on the consistency of time, running the ntp daemon will provide a smoother adjustment as meuh states.

Answer (score 0):

Your `ntpq -p` output shows an offset of `-66949.` milliseconds with the selected (by `*` in col 1) reference. When this was stabilised, ntp did a step of 66 seconds to fix the time, corresponding to your observed jump from  20:17:59  to 20:19:16 (+10 seconds between observations).

You can usually run `ntpdate` to get an good estimate of the time, then run ntpd to slowly stabilise and then slowly move the clock into sync.

I dont know what your OS provides, but look for options `-x` and `-g`, and configurations with `iburst` at the end of the `server ...` line.

Comment: To be honest, I don't understand your answer and what I have to do. `ntpdate` is deprecated on SLES 11 SP2 and is doing - as I can see it - nothing. The time changed now again after 14 minutes...

Comment: If it is deprecated that should mean it is built-in to ntpd, so `ntpd -x` and `ntpd -g` should work, though I dont know how ntpd is started on SLES. However, in your `/etc/ntp.conf` you should have a line beginning `server` to which you can add `iburst` at the end to make it synch up faster at the start.

Comment: In `/etc/ntp.conf` each `server` line had the `iburst` tag. I ran `ntpd -x` and `ntpd -g`. Now the gap changed from 66 seconds to 54 seconds. Is it getting *better* or not?

Comment: I dont think the gap is important, but the time taken to get in sync. It shouldnt take 8 minutes at startup.

Comment: I have the feeling there is a misunderstanding. The problem is **not** that it takes 8 minutes to get in sync at startup, the problem is, that the time **changes** to a wrong value within 8 minutes once it was set correctly [e.q. the service started]. This is the problem! I don't understand what *forces* the system to change the time. I couldn't find anything in any log file.

Comment: `ntpdate` is not (always) the same as `ntpd` with the `-x` or `-g` flags, despite the maintainers insisting it is.

Comment: @AlBundy if the time changes to a wrong value, perhaps it's getting that wrong value from the remote system. Generally it's recommended to have three (or five) remote time servers to avoid this possibility. Have you considered using some of the [pool.ntp.org servers](http://http://www.pool.ntp.org/)?